# Is it necessary to encrypt data in Firebase realtime database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, encryption, aes

Because i read that Firebase already encrypted the data in Firebase:

The data is encrypted in transit, and it is stored on encrypted disks on the servers. If you enable local persistence on the device, the on device data is not encrypted.

But administrators of the app can see the data in the Firebase console.

I use AES encryption, when i use it, it doubled the size of the text...
Is it more secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether extra encryption is necessary is subjective here, as it depends almost exclusive on your (function and regulatory) requirements, so it's for use to answer what you need to do.

If you don't want project administrators to be able to see the data that your users entered, you will indeed either need to encrypt the data, or remove their rights to see the data in the Firebase console altogether.

To learn more about end to end encryption, I recommend checking some of these top results when searching for [end to end encryption in firebase realtime database](https://www.google.com/search?q=end+to+end+encryption+in+firebase+realtime+database). This *may* indeed inflate your data size.

Comment: But what if someone hack my app to get access to firebase credentials (Api key...), He/She will be able to read my data...

Comment: If somebody gets access to your credentials, their access to the user data is but one of *many* problems. They could just as easily use GCP computing power to run whatever cracking tool they want on as many CPUs as they want, all on your billing account. So yes, that is a valid concern - but end-to-end encryption is probably not the first barrier I would focus on there. That said, if it is a requirement of *your* application or regulation you need to need, then I recommend clicking that link and implementing it. At that point the data size inflation is also a given, and not a question/choice.